# How to get component instance via code Joomla 1.7

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

I want to use my Joomla 1.7 Components from a webservices placed inside the same server.

In other words, I have another file that will be used by mobile-apps to do stuff.

I'd like to use joomla core functions nor having to duplicate code nor having to make direct inserts in the DB bypassing joomla and formatting them to match "what Joomla would do".

For now I am able to get the DBO objects and make queries using joomla, but I want to use every component I need.
For example,

```
<?php
    if (!defined('_JEXEC')) { define('_JEXEC', 1); }
    if (!defined('DS')) {  define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); }

    if (file_exists(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/defines.php')) 
    { 
        include_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/defines.php'; 
    }

    if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
    {
        define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
        require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
    }

    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

    // Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
    JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;
    $db = JFactory::getDocument()->getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('r.id');
    $query->from('#__asd as r');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__xxx cc on cc.recipe_id = r.id');
    // Prepare where clause
    $query->where('r.published = 1');
    $query->group('r.id');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $objectsList = $db->loadObjectList();
    $res = formatResult($objectsList);


function formatResult($obj)
{
    if($obj === NULL || !is_array($obj)){ return array('data' => 'Vuoto', 'code' => 0); }
    return array('data' => (array)$obj, 'code' => 1);
}
?>
```

EDIT: More specifically, I have installed ([JFBconnect](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/facebook-integration/7215)) and I want its functionality to login and register users from app.

Comment: can I recommend you first upgrade to Joomla 2.5 which is literally a 1 click update. As for your actual "question", I'm rather confused as to what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: If I could, I definetly would.... but people who worked at this project before made that impossible: they altered all core functions to achieve ad-hoc results. Boss said that's not gonna happen :)
I want to create webservices, to use the website funcions (like register posts, register users, ecc) by mobile application. Since those functionalities are already online on the website I want them also by mobile.

Comment: wow well they were silly do have done that. as mentioned before, can you please explain what you're trying to achieve in a little more detail? ;)

Comment: updated both comments and question

Comment: What you're trying to do is a massive amount of work, especially given the broad nature of the functionality you're after. (By the way a very good reason to upgrade is the new Ajax core that's been added to 3.2 which would make this much easier http://developer.joomla.org/news/566-joomla-3-2-alpha-released.html).